# computer not coming on failed to restart

Tags: boot

my sony vaio fit series SVF15AA1Q1 is not coming on. just got the laptop yesterday and I downloaded all the vaio updates today upon downloading the last one I think the one that has to do with firmware. It told me it has to restart, for almost 2 hour now the system has been attempting to restart (black screen and the system is just making some clicks - the type of sound when a system is starting) but no avail. Please tell me what to do as I can't remove the battery to force a shutdown. Appreciate

Comment: The "clicking" is probably your HDD.  Check its health.  As-is this shows no actual research effort, and is much too broad (if you even consider it a question, which I don't. ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Try to forcibly shutdown the laptop by long pressing the power button (5-7 sec). Once it is off use Vaio restore button to restore your laptop to factory defaults. Running a hardware diagnostics is recommended.